# Does Quarkus have an annotation or method similar to @ConditionalOnBean?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

I am developing an extension for Quarkus, and I'm facing certain problems. Within the deployment module, I need to decide whether or not to instantiate beanB depending on the existence of a user-defined beanA.

```
    @BuildStep
    void registerBeanProducers(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans,
                               BuildProducer<ReflectiveClassBuildItem> reflectiveClasses,
                               CombinedIndexBuildItem combinedIndexBuildItem) {
        AdditionalBeanBuildItem.Builder builder = AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder().setUnremovable();

        if (container has user-defined beanA) {
            builder.addBeanClass(beanB.class);
        }
        additionalBeans.produce(builder.build());
    }
```

Are there any relevant materials that I can refer to for this aspect, or could you provide a general direction of thought?

```
@BuildStep
    void registerBeanProducers(BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem beanArchiveIndexBuildItem,
                               BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans,
                               BuildProducer<ReflectiveClassBuildItem> reflectiveClasses) {
        Collection<ClassInfo> classInfos = beanArchiveIndexBuildItem.getIndex().getKnownUsers(beanA.class);
        if (!classInfos.isEmpty()) {
            AdditionalBeanBuildItem.Builder builder = AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder().setUnremovable();
            builder.addBeanClass(beanB.class);
            additionalBeans.produce(builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: At the point `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`s are consumed (so all the `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`s must be produced before that), bean discovery has not yet started. So the information you're looking for is not available. You can consume the `BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem`, look at the Jandex index and approximate the bean discovery process yourself. (I'm saying "approximate" because you're unlikely to implement it all, but for simple cases, it should be enough.) I would suggest you describe your use case in detail, because there are likely other, better solutions.

Comment: In my extension, there's a class beanB annotated with ApplicationScope. I want the beanB to be registered using AdditionalBeanBuildItem.addBeanClass(beanB) only when a user-defined beanA exists. Within beanB, there are annotations like Scheduled that should take effect, which define timer tasks.  @Ladicek

Comment: What's `beanA`? Is that like a class whose name you know upfront? Or do you need to detect it in a more complicated fashion? If it's the former, you can just lookup the class from the bean archive index and if it's there, you register your additional bean.

Comment: I know the return type of this beanA, Can I look up class from the bean archive index? @Ladicek

Comment: Yeah. Instead of `CombinedIndexBuildItem`, I would consume `BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem` and do `getIndex().getClassByName("beanA")` to see if `beanA` is present in the bean archive. This does not really answer the question "does bean with class `beanA` exist?", but for your use case case, it should be a good enough approximation.

Comment: BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem That really solves my problem, what do I instantiate beanB with when I make that judgment, AdditionalBeanBuildItem doesn't seem to work @Ladicek

Comment: I mean besides AdditionalBeanBuildItem what method can help me to add bean into the container, because BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem and AdditionalBeanBuildItem can't work at the same time. @Ladicek

Comment: Why does it not work? Is there a build step cycle? That shouldn't be the case, but I might have made a mistake...

Comment: When I use the BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem to judge beanA, Then AdditionalBeanBuildItem. AddBeanClass (beanB) happens when the following error: Java. Lang. RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.ChainBuildException: Cycle detected:     @Ladicek

Comment: That seems weird, this build step https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/ddcb1448911c645952954197b14b8eccf204f093/extensions/arc/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/arc/deployment/ArcProcessor.java#L157 consumes both build items, so it should be possible to have a build step that consumes `BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem` and produces `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`. Does your build step maybe consume or produce any other build items?

Comment: I added some details in the question, please help to check. I did produce my beanB and then something went wrong: Cycle detected.  @Ladicek

Comment: Can you remove the producer of `ReflectiveClassBuildItem`? It doesn't seem used, and might be causing the cycle. Also, `getKnownUsers()` is _not_ what you need; you should use `getClassByName()`.

Comment: Thank you.To check the console information should be AdditionalBeanBuildItem and BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem resulted in the cycle   io.quarkus.arc.deployment.BeanArchiveProcessor#build produced class io.quarkus.arc.deployment.BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem
  to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.deployment.xxxxProcessor#registerBeanProducers produced class io.quarkus.arc.deployment.AdditionalBeanBuildItem.   What's an alternative to AdditionalBeanBuildIte.   @Ladicek